# Django model property get current_user id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add a property in my model where I would like to check if current value like by the user or not.

For that I have written the code:

```
@property
def current_user_like(self):
    looks = get_object_or_404(Looks, pk=self.id)
    user_likes_this = looks.like_set.filter(user=144) and True or False
    return user_likes_this
```

So my question is can I do like this:

```
@property
def current_user_like(self):
    looks = get_object_or_404(Looks, pk=self.id)
    user_likes_this = looks.like_set.filter(user=request.user.id) and True or False
    return user_likes_this
```

What would be the best way to achieve this functionality I am using Django rest framework so I added this property to the serializer. Can I do this if not what else I should do?

Serializer:

```
class LookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    user_profile_image = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    current_user_like = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Looks
        fields = ('__all__')
```

In views I am retrieving using this code:

```
    looks = Looks.objects.all()
    serializer = LookSerializer(looks,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Models are request-onaware, so no. But you do not need that in the Django rest framework. It is also not efficient, since it would result in an N+1 problem even if that was possible. You can use annotations. Can you share relevant models serialzers and views?

Comment: I am trying to add this into the model because I am using this model to query data multiple times. And I want to add this here so that I don't have to change other files.

Comment: well models are request *unaware*, so the concept of a request (and its attached logged in user) do not exist at the model layer..

Comment: Can you give me any answer using annotations

Comment: @NilaySingh for that you need to provide the relevant model and view.
and refer to the docs about annotation, there are some great examples there.

Comment: to add to @WillemVanOnsem, you rather access this data in the serializer or in the view.
if likes are associated with a user then for example you can query the desired user in the view (if using ViewSet then 'self.request.user') and then filter all the likes they received from another user.